# Arduino Makefile: How to save sensor data to file in the computer?

Tags: c++, makefile, arduino

I am using a command-line interface package called Arduino Makefile on Linux. I set up a sensor on Arduino Uno to print temperature and humidity data to an LCD.

I have already searched for possible solutions such as [Save to CSV file from Arduino](http://www.hackerscapes.com/2014/11/how-to-save-data-from-arduino-to-a-csv-file-using-processing/), which has code that is repeated on different websites and forums such as [researchgate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_can_I_save_data_directly_in_the_pc_using_an_Arduino_UNO).

I tried using their code. However, the code line:

```
import processing.serial.*;
```

gives me the error:

```
thermo.ino:3:1: error: ‘import’ does not name a type
 import processing.serial.*;
 ^
```

How would this error be solved? Or is there another way to save the sensor data into a file stored in my computer?

By the way, my computer is directly connected to the Arduino Uno using a USB cable.

Comment: processing is different a Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are running that code in the Arduino IDE but you have to run it in the Processing IDE.

1. Download processing from [here](https://processing.org/download/).
2. Then download the libraries for Processing [here](https://github.com/firmata/processing/releases/tag/latest).
3. Unzip the library and copy the "Arduino" folder into the "libraries" sub-folder of your Processing Sketchbook. In my case "C:\Users\Ricardo\Documents\Processing\libraries".

Now execute the **first** code that you get from the tutorial that you [mentioned before](http://www.hackerscapes.com/2014/11/how-to-save-data-from-arduino-to-a-csv-file-using-processing/) in the **Arduino IDE**. Execute the **second** code from that page in the **Processing IDE**.

That should work!

Note:

This [link](https://playground.arduino.cc/Interfacing/Processing) is pretty useful

Comment: I'm not using the Arduino IDE, I'm using Arduino Makefile which is a command line interface package.

Comment: okey but you also have to use Processing because arduino language do not have "import" if you follow the steps as i said you will be able to save the data, or use python serial to get the values and save it in a file